# Repair OGG files that have been extracted without a header

Tags: audio, extract, file-corruption, ogg

I have recently used a tool called FSBextractor to extract audio from a videogame.  The program warns me that the files do not have headers and will not be playable.  Upon extraction, the files are indeed not playable (using MPC-HC).

Is it possible to repair these files?  How unique is an Ogg Vorbis header?  Is it possible to extract a header from another file and insert it into the broken files?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I recorded a stream using:

```
mplayer -dumpstream  "https://radio.tildeverse.org/radio/8000/radio.ogg" -dumpfile "/home/adamd/temp/StreamDump.ogg"
```

When completed it was playable with occasional skips and errors. Errors were `Error parsing the packet header.`. Progress indication and the ability to move to specific locations in the playback did NOT work.

Fixed by running: `ffmpeg -i StreamDump.ogg SD.ogg`

Perhaps it will work for you.

Comment: Just be warned—this is actually re-encoding the audio file rather than simply re-packaging it, so it's not a lossless process.